# get amount between range

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

This a simple my table

```
+-----------+----------------+-----------+
|     id    |       date     |   meter   |
------------+----------------+-----------+
|      1    |  2103-11-01    |   5       |
|      2    |  2103-11-10    |   8       |
|      4    |  2103-11-14    |   10      |
|      6    |  2103-11-20    |   18      |
|      7    |  2103-11-25    |   25      |
|      10   |  2103-11-29    |   30      |
+-----------+----------------+-----------+
```

how do I get the results to the use of meters between two ranges of the results of recording time,
like bellow

```
+----------------+----------------+-------+-----+--------+ 
|    date1       |    date2       | start | end | amount | 
+----------------+----------------+-------+-----+--------+
|    2013-11-01  |    2013-11-10  |  5    |  8  |  3     | 
|    2013-11-10  |    2013-11-14  |  8    | 10  |  2     | 
|    2013-11-14  |    2013-11-20  | 10    | 18  |  8     | 
|    2013-11-20  |    2013-11-25  | 18    | 25  |  7     | 
|    2013-11-25  |    2013-11-29  | 25    | 30  |  5     | 
+----------------+----------------+-------+-----+--------+
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They aren't the same thing.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, what version?

Comment: thank you for your time and attention you all,
now complete and running well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:
I got it:

```
select meters1.date as date1, min(meters2.date) as date2, meters1.meter as start,
  meters2.meter as end, (meters2.meter - meters1.meter) as amount
  from meters meters1, meters meters2 where meters1.date < meters2.date
   group by date1;
```

Outputs:

```
+------------+------------+-------+-----+--------+
| date1      | date2      | start | end | amount |
+------------+------------+-------+-----+--------+
| 2013-11-01 | 2013-11-10 |     5 |   8 |      3 |
| 2013-11-10 | 2013-11-14 |     8 |  10 |      2 |
| 2013-11-14 | 2013-11-20 |    10 |  18 |      8 |
| 2013-11-20 | 2013-11-25 |    18 |  25 |      7 |
| 2013-11-25 | 2013-11-29 |    25 |  30 |      5 |
+------------+------------+-------+-----+--------+
```

Original Post:

This is most of the way there:

```
select meters1.date as date1, meters2.date as date2, meters1.meter as start,
  meters2.meter as end, (meters2.meter - meters1.meter) as amount
  from meters meters1, meters meters2 having date1 < date2 order by date1;
```

It outputs:

```
+------------+------------+-------+-----+--------+
| date1      | date2      | start | end | amount |
+------------+------------+-------+-----+--------+
| 2013-11-01 | 2013-11-10 |     5 |   8 |      3 |
| 2013-11-01 | 2013-11-20 |     5 |  18 |     13 |
| 2013-11-01 | 2013-11-29 |     5 |  30 |     25 |
| 2013-11-01 | 2013-11-14 |     5 |  10 |      5 |
| 2013-11-01 | 2013-11-25 |     5 |  25 |     20 |
| 2013-11-10 | 2013-11-20 |     8 |  18 |     10 |
| 2013-11-10 | 2013-11-29 |     8 |  30 |     22 |
| 2013-11-10 | 2013-11-14 |     8 |  10 |      2 |
| 2013-11-10 | 2013-11-25 |     8 |  25 |     17 |
| 2013-11-14 | 2013-11-25 |    10 |  25 |     15 |
| 2013-11-14 | 2013-11-20 |    10 |  18 |      8 |
| 2013-11-14 | 2013-11-29 |    10 |  30 |     20 |
| 2013-11-20 | 2013-11-25 |    18 |  25 |      7 |
| 2013-11-20 | 2013-11-29 |    18 |  30 |     12 |
| 2013-11-25 | 2013-11-29 |    25 |  30 |      5 |
+------------+------------+-------+-----+--------+
```

Comment: This is close but it is adding some extra rows

Comment: thank you for your time and attention,
now complete and running well

Answer (score 1):

If it's SQL server try it this way

```sql
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) rnum
    FROM table1
)
SELECT c.date date1, p.date date2, c.meter [start], p.meter [end], p.meter - c.meter amount
  FROM cte c JOIN cte p
    ON c.rnum = p.rnum - 1
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad552/6)** demo

---

If it's MySQL then you can do

```sql
SELECT date1, date2, meter1, meter2, meter2 - meter1 amount
  FROM
(
  SELECT @d date2, date date1, @m meter2, meter meter1, @d := date, @m := meter
    FROM table1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @d := NULL, @m := NULL) i
   ORDER BY date DESC
) q
 WHERE date2 IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY date1
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18dd8/6)** demo

Output in both cases:

```
|      DATE1 |      DATE2 | START | END | AMOUNT |
|------------|------------|-------|-----|--------|
| 2103-11-01 | 2103-11-10 |     5 |   8 |      3 |
| 2103-11-10 | 2103-11-14 |     8 |  10 |      2 |
| 2103-11-14 | 2103-11-20 |    10 |  18 |      8 |
| 2103-11-20 | 2103-11-25 |    18 |  25 |      7 |
| 2103-11-25 | 2103-11-29 |    25 |  30 |      5 |
```

Comment: Come on... that's very messy :P Anyway, it gets the job done. Just one comment. The type of the variables can not be dates so it uses a string representation (it is clearer in the Fiddle). In order to fix that it is possible to cast the variable to a date: `CAST(@d AS date) date2`

Answer (score 1):

MySql

```
SELECT DATES.date1,
       DATES.date2,
       m1.meter as start,
       m2.meter as end,
       m2.meter - m1.meter as amount
FROM
  (SELECT date as date1,
       (SELECT min(date)
        FROM tableName t2
        WHERE t2.date > t1.date) as date2
   FROM tableName t1
  )DATES,
  tableName m1,
  tableName m2
WHERE DATES.date2 IS NOT NULL
  AND m1.date = DATES.date1
  AND m2.date = DATES.date2
ORDER BY DATES.date1
```

[sqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2d8e/1/0)

in MS-SQL SERVER 2002 change the word `end` to `"end"` as it complains about syntax near `end`

Comment: Well, not necessarily `MySQL`. This would work in any DBMS :) But probably would not be the way to go for other more-feature-rich DBMS

Comment: I still don't quite understand the `Group By` less columns than in the select list (other than aggregate calls) I don't quite trust it because i don't know what to expect (unless i am grouping by all fields in the select other than aggregate functions)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL, then a self-join will work well here. Join the table to itself, using an `ON` clause to make sure you don't join the same record to itself. This will give you `((N * N) - N)` permutations of your data, where `N` is the number of original rows.

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    tableName first
JOIN
    tableName second
    ON first.id != second.id
```

Then, it's all about `SELECT`ing the right stuff (including the calculation of the difference between the two `meter` values). To get the columns in the result set you posted, you'd probably want to `SELECT`:

```
first.date AS date1,
second.date AS date2,
first.meter AS start,
second.meter AS end,
ABS(first.meter - second.meter) AS amount
```

*Edit*
Ah, I see. I'd envisioned something like a inter-city mileage chart that you used to see on road maps (where you'd have the same cities in the rows and columns, and the cell in the intersection would indicate the number of miles between those two cities.

But it looks like you just want to compare values from one date to the next. If that's the case, you can take advantage of the way MySQL handles `GROUP`ing and `ORDER`ing... but be careful, because I'm not sure this is guaranteed:

```
mysql> SELECT 
    table1.date AS date1, 
    table2.date AS date2, 
    table1.meter AS start, 
    table2.meter AS end, 
    ABS(table1.meter - table2.meter) AS amount 
FROM tableName table1 
JOIN tableName table2 
    WHERE table2.date > table1.date 
GROUP BY table1.date 
ORDER BY table2.date - table1.date;
+---------------------+---------------------+-------+------+--------+
| date1               | date2               | start | end  | amount |
+---------------------+---------------------+-------+------+--------+
| 2103-11-25 00:00:00 | 2103-11-29 00:00:00 |    25 |   30 |      5 |
| 2103-11-10 00:00:00 | 2103-11-14 00:00:00 |     8 |   10 |      2 |
| 2103-11-20 00:00:00 | 2103-11-25 00:00:00 |    18 |   25 |      7 |
| 2103-11-14 00:00:00 | 2103-11-20 00:00:00 |    10 |   18 |      8 |
| 2103-11-01 00:00:00 | 2103-11-10 00:00:00 |     5 |    8 |      3 |
+---------------------+---------------------+-------+------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Are you sure this would work? I mean, how are you joining id 4 with id 6 together leaving out all the other combinations? I appreciate a fiddle to see this working, if possible

Comment: Just updated my answer. I tried to stay away from sub-queries, but you may want to explore them as an option, since they can help you guarantee ordering, grouping, etc. Here's a fiddle showing this answer in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e217/3

Comment: Ok, I see you're basically doing a greatest-n-per-group in there. However, the grouping is not correct. Take a look this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html) particularly this phrase `The server is free to choose any value from each group`. The idea of your query is good. However, in order to make it work (always and not when the server happens to choose the minimal values of each row) you should probably duplicate the query in order to perform any of typical greatest-n-per-group solutions. Although inefficient, that solution would work in any DBMS :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't made it clear whether you're really using mySQL or SQL Server but I'm posting a solution that works for SQL 2008 and above.  Might work for 2005 but I can't test that.

```
-- Set up a temp table with sample data
DECLARE @testData AS TABLE(
    id int,
    dt date,
    meter int)

INSERT @testData(id, dt, meter) VALUES 
     (1, '2013-11-01', 5)
    ,(2, '2013-11-10', 8)
    ,(4, '2013-11-14', 10)
    ,(6, '2013-11-20', 18)
    ,(7, '2013-11-25', 25)
    ,(10, '2013-11-29',30)
---------------------------------------------

-- Begin SQL Server solution
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rownum
        ,id
        ,dt
        ,meter
    FROM 
        @testData AS [date2] 
)

SELECT 
     t1.id
    ,t1.dt AS [date1]
    ,t2.dt AS [date2]
    ,t1.meter AS [start]
    ,t2.meter AS [end]
    ,t2.meter - t1.meter AS [amount]
FROM 
    cte t1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cte t2 ON (t2.rownum = t1.rownum + 1)
WHERE 
    t2.dt IS NOT NULL
```